# c# store data in Excel file

Tags: c#, xml, excel

I am obtaining data from a database that is returned in an XML string.  What is the best way to then store this in an Excel file?  Is there an XML - Excel tool, or is there an interim step?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably just to loop through the XML-data either with XMLDocument or XDocument (linq) and write to a csv-file. The advantage with at csv file is that its readable with any text editor or other spreadsheet software.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the data using the `XMLDocument` and then insert the data in the excel using `Microsoft.Excel` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Providing you're talking about Excel 2007 or newer, the format is XML-based. Check out any resources on OpenXML such as http://openxmldeveloper.org/ for details, or there's a video tutorial here that shows it http://www.asp.net/linq/videos/how-do-i-create-excel-spreadsheets-using-linq-to-xml . There's even things like http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/ and an SDK here http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en .